# How to find the frame of a SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable

Tags: uikit, interop, swiftui

I'm trying to wrap a custom subclass of `UILabel` in `UIViewRepresentable` to use it in SwiftUI. I'm using `.sizeToFit` and printing the frame, and it looks right while it's in the wrapper:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomUILabel {
    let view = CustomUILabel()
    view.customProperty = model.customProperty
    view.sizeToFit()
    print(model.latex,view.frame.size) // this prints the correct size, how to propagate?
    return view
}
```

but when I run this in a `VStack`, it draws the `UIViewRepresentable` with the maximum space possible.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ geometry in
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame( height: geometry.size.height/2 - 5 + self.draggedOffset.height)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(height: 10)
            custonView(model:self.model)
            Spacer()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to propagate the size of the `UIView` to its parent, similar to how you use preference keys on a native `SwiftUI` view?

Comment: Please show the code where you use this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to use of `GeometryReader`

Try to use

```
custonView(model:self.model)
    .fixedSize()
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm trying to make a simple UILabel not fill the screen.

Comment: @malhal, it only means that your situation is different - post your question with your code, and then somebody here could help you.

Answer (score 2):

When using `UIViewRepresentable`, the greediness you describe is controlled using the `contentHuggingPriority`, just like it always was in UIKit.

So in your `makeUIView` function, you can do this:

```
// resist being made larger than the intrinsicContentSize
view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
```